# How can we find the sum of the diagonal elements and then store in different array?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I want to get sum of a 2D matrix and then store in another array, e.g. if we have `a[][][]` then `a[0][1]` is stored in another array `b[] at b[1],a[0][1]+a[1][0]`, at b[2] it will be `a[0][2]+a[1][1]+a[2][0]` ... and so on.

Comment: In which language ? c ,c#,Java ?

Comment: m tryng this 1 in java.

Answer (score 0):

array is  b[] at b[1],a[0][1]+a[1][0],,at b[2]

as diagonal elements are on same positions of row and column

```
sum=0;
for(i=0; i<b.length;i++)
{
    sum+=b[i][i];
 }
 print sum;
```

Comment: this 1 is to get sum of identical diagonal elements...i need for all

Comment: sum=0; coloumn_count=b.length-1;
for(i=0; i<b.length;i++)
{
    sum+=b[i][coloumn_count]; coloumn_count--;
 }
 print sum;

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the column count

```
sum=0; 
column_count=b.length-1; 
for(i=0; i<b.length;i++) 
{ 
 sum+=b[i][i];
 sum+=b[i][column_count];
  column_count--;
} 
print sum;
```